# How to include % in string formats in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, string-formatting

I am trying to append `%` in a string using string formats.

I am trying to get the below output:

```
a : [" name like '%FTa0213' "]
```

**Try 1 :**

```
a = [ ] 
b = {'by_name':"FTa0213"}
a.append(" name like "%" %s' " %b['by_name'])
print "a :",a
```

**Error :**

```
a.append(" name like "%" %s' " %b['by_name'])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

**Try 2:**

```
a = [ ] 
b = {'by_name':"FTa0213"}
c = "%"
a.append(" name like '{0}{1}' ".format(c,b['by_name'])
print "a :",a
```

**Error :**

```
 print "a :",a
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I include a `%` in my formatted string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To include a percent `%` into a string which will be used for a printf style string format, simply escape the `%` by including a double percent `%%`

```
a = []
b = {'by_name': "FTa0213"}
a.append(" name like %%%s' " % b['by_name'])
print "a :", a
```

([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting))

Answer (score 6):

**In your first try**, the way you use "%" is wrong; the code below could work for your first try.

```
a.append( "name like %%%s" % b['by_name'])
```

Since the "%" is special in python string, so you need to add a "%" before the real "%" to escape.

**In your second try**, there is nothing wrong in your print, you forgot a `")"` in your `a.append` line. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

just put the % there, no need to set the variable

```
a = [ ] 
b = {'by_name':"FTa0213"}
a.append(" name like '%{}' ".format(b['by_name']))
print "a :",a
```

the output is

> a : [" name like '%FTa0213' "]

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the percent sign by doubling it.

```
a = [] 
b = {'by_name': "FTa0213"}
a.append(" name like '%%%s' " % b['by_name'])
print "a :", a
```

**output**

```
a : [" name like '%FTa0213' "]
```

However, I think it's clearer to use the `format` method:

```
a = [ ] 
b = {'by_name': "FTa0213"}
a.append(" name like '%{by_name}' ".format(**b))
print "a :", a
```